# How to convert sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo to java.util.TimeZone in Grails

Tags: types

How to convert sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo to java.util.TimeZone in Grails

How would you convert this ZoneInfo to type TimeZone in Grails

I assuming the cast would be something like this but grails it is not converting it.

TimeZone s  = zoneInfo as Timestamp or TimeZone s = (Timezone)zoneInfo

Comment: Why using `zoneInfo as Timestamp` when trying to convert to `Timezone`? `TimeZone tz = zi as TimeZone` should work.

Comment: Btw, why do you really need this conversion? Since `ZoneInfo` is an implementation subclass of `TimeZone` and `zi instanceof TimeZone` is going to be `true`.

Comment: because of ```groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format() is applicable for argument types: (String, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo) values: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]]
    Possible solutions: format(java.lang.String, java.util.TimeZone), format(java.lang.String), toYear(), from(java.time.Instant)```